# Idiomatic way to represent pagination in JSON-LD / semantic web?

Tags: rdf, owl, semantic-web, json-ld

I am working on an API that serves data  that is represented as linked data. Currently responses are JSON-LD graphs. So far the API simply serves objects like this:

```json
{ "@context": "https://my-context-url...",
  "@graph": [ {object using terms in my-context}, ... ]
}
```

Now I want to support pagination, because I want that response to support incomplete data when the dataset is large. The requester handles this by having `limit` and `offset` from the URL parameters, and the server may respond saying where to start the next page.

This feels like a very common pattern that would have a standard vocabulary for basic networking patterns as well as whatever data structure you like. But in my searches I can't for the life of me find a standard W3C ontology that has a term like `nextPage`.

My intuition is that I need to add a term like this in the response:

```json
{ "@context": [
    "https://my-context-url...",
    { "next_page_offset":  "????"
    }
  ],
  "next_page_offset": 1000,
  "@graph": [ {object using terms in my-context}, ... ]
}
```

Is there such a standard? If not, am I thinking about this wrong? Possibly this is idiomatically handled without a shortcut? I am not quite clear on how to deal with verbs/relations that don't have an IRI nor a shortcut. I am new-ish to semantic web so I'm ready to believe this is supposed to be handled at some wrapper layer, or that semantic web is not intended for data that is ephemeral or something like that.

Comment: Not sure if it’s applicable in your case, but in the context of a [Linked Data Platform](https://www.w3.org/TR/2015/REC-ldp-20150226/), there is a pattern described: [Paging](https://www.w3.org/TR/ldp-paging/): "a HTTP-based protocol for clients and servers to be able to efficiently retrieve large Linked Data Platform Resource representations by splitting up the responses into separate URL-addressable page resources"

Comment: http://www.hydra-cg.com/spec/latest/core/#hydra:next

Comment: dang, These are both super useful links. The Hydra vocabulary answers my question as phrased, but now i'm thinking through whether I would rather conform to LDP Paging, which works a little differently (uses headers to avoid treating a Page as a Resource, which use of hydra#next for this purpose would imply). Thanks to you both.

Comment: You could go with both. Differentiating between a page and a resource is definitely useful to prevent semantic coagulation; you'd usually redirect from the resource URI via 303 See Other to the page describing it. Then you can use `Link` in the appropriate places, and describe the page using Hydra.

Answer (score 1):

There's [SPIN - SPARQL Syntax W3c Member Submission](https://www.w3.org/Submission/spin-sparql/) from 2011, which is a vocabulary for expressing SPARQL queries in RDF.  If defines terms for SPARQL's `limit` and `offset`:

> A LIMIT keyword is mapped into an integer value of sp:limit [`http://spinrdf.org/sp#limit`]. Similarly, OFFSET is stored with sp:offset [`http://spinrdf.org/sp#offset`].

Note that the results of LIMIT and OFFSET only really matter if there's also an ORDER BY, so you may want that, too:

> If an ORDER BY statement is present in a query, then the SPIN query object will have a property sp:orderBy [`http://spinrdf.org/sp#orderBy`]that points to an rdf:List.

[The complete ontology](https://spinrdf.org/sp) is available from [SPIN - SPARQL Inferencing Notation](https://spinrdf.org).

Whether these terms are broadly used outside of representing SPARQL queries, I don't know, but the connection to a well-known query language for RDF and the fact that they're used for exactly the purposes that you're describing seems like they'd be reasonable terms to lean on.